# Duplicated ID on JSF custom tag when nesting tags

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra, custom-tag

I'm migrating some composites to custom tags because of performance issues. When using composites all Ids are properly generated, but when using custom tags I'm having the duplicated Id Exception, even I created a custom EL expression for generating a new ID.

After some research, it seems it's because the tags attributes are inherited when nesting the tag:

```
<far:fcontainer name="**father1**" type="panel">
 <far:fcontainer type="panel">
  <far:fcontainer type="panel">child 3</farTag:fcontainer>
 </far:fcontainer>
</far:fcontainer>
```

In the example, the first fcontainer should have the id **father1** and the nested ones should have the ID generated, but this is what I have:

```
<div id="**father1**" class="ui-widget-content">
 <div id="**father1**" class="ui-widget-content">
  <div id="**father1**" class="ui-widget-content">child3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The custom tag is:

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="#{type == 'panel'?'ui-widget-content':''}" 
         id="#{empty name ? far:generateId() : name}">
        <ui:insert />
    </p:outputPanel>
<ui:composition>
```

Is this normal? Is there any workaround?

Tested on Mojarra 2.1.26.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** tested on MyFaces 2.1.12 and seems to work fine, Mojarra's bug?

Comment: In MyFaces there was a big fix the id generation algorithm to make it more predictable and unique and in that way more stable. It is a long story, a lot of hard work there, but in my opinion it is the best solution to this problem so far. It seems Mojarra still has the old facelets 1.1.x algorithm, and I suppose the synthom you see in Mojarra is caused by than, in MyFaces 2.2.x it was discovered some important flaws of that algorithm and remember facelets code was donated to MyFaces too, so both implementations originally used the same code there.

Comment: You can concatenate some word before the generated tag? did you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to this bug would be to always use the custom EL expression, and in it you can first check whether the parent component has the attribute set or not.